# How to create a unique index with conditional and subquery in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, constraints

I use PGSQL and try add the index below.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX fk_client ON user_client (fk_client) WHERE fk_client NOT IN(SELECT fk_client FROM legal_entity);
```

But ... It is not possible, because there is allowed run a sub query in the creation of an index.

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  cannot use subquery in index predicate
```

Is there any way to solve this problem?

[image]

The above model Represents the situation of the case.

- The client Can Be either an ordinary person, or a company
- If an ordinary person is, she will not have FK in "legal_entity" table.
- If an ordinary person is, she Should only one record in "user_client" table.

With index does not, but is there any way to solve this problem?...

Script generate tables:

```
-- user is a special word, then renamed to users
CREATE TABLE users (
    id_user INT,
    name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT user_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id_user)
);

CREATE TABLE client (
    id_client INT,
    CONSTRAINT client_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id_client)
);

CREATE TABLE legal_entity (
    fk_client INT,
    federal_id VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT legal_entity_pkey PRIMARY KEY (fk_client),
    CONSTRAINT legal_entity_fkey FOREIGN KEY (fk_client) REFERENCES client (id_client)
);

CREATE TABLE user_client (
    fk_client INT,
    fk_user INT,
    CONSTRAINT user_client_pkey PRIMARY KEY (fk_client, fk_user),
    CONSTRAINT user_client_fkey_1 FOREIGN KEY (fk_client) REFERENCES client (id_client),
    CONSTRAINT user_client_fkey_2 FOREIGN KEY (fk_user) REFERENCES users (id_user)
);
```

Comment: Please give an actual table definition instead of a textual description.

Comment: #Done - Hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry I don't read grafics. I read SQL.

Comment: Great! Now edited the question and added scripts to create tables.

Comment: That's better. The change in your model could possibly invalidate my answer. Why didn't you add a complete model to your initial Q? That would have saved us from the guesswork and the typing.

Comment: Your answer may also be edited in addition the model is the same, the difference is that now there is a context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The downside to using a rules is that rules simply rewrite the query after it is parsed so if the data is added through a trigger, it will not fire. It's safer to add a CHECK constraint that calls a function with your logic. If I follow your logic correctly, it should be something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_user_client(fkc int) 
  RETURNS boolean AS
$$
DECLARE
  i int;
BEGIN
  SELECT count(*) INTO i FROM legal_entity WHERE fk_client = fkc;
  IF (i > 0) THEN
    RETURN true;
  END IF;

  SELECT count(*) INTO i FROM user_client WHERE fk_client = fkc;
  IF (i = 0) THEN
    RETURN true;
  END IF;

  RETURN false;  
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

ALTER TABLE user_client ADD CONSTRAINT unique_user CHECK (check_user_client(fk_client));
```

Comment: Thank's! I will test when I have time.

Comment: Thank you! The function works perfectly, sorry for the delay in giving feedback

Comment: How do you deal with concurrent transactions here? They may all satisfy the condition and will then commit, putting the table in inconsistent state.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by adding a rule table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE RULE rule_test AS ON INSERT
    TO user_client WHERE (
        (SELECT fk_client FROM legal_entity WHERE fk_client = new.fk_client) IS NULL) AND (
        (SELECT fk_client FROM user_client WHERE fk_client = new.fk_client) IS NOT NULL)
    DO INSTEAD NOTHING;
```

Answer (score -2):

```
DROP SCHEMA tmp CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA tmp ;
SET search_path=tmp;

CREATE TABLE foo
        ( id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        );
CREATE TABLE tbl_relation
        ( id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , foo_id INTEGER REFERENCES foo(id)
        , fk_1 INTEGER
        );

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX fk_1 ON tbl_relation (fk_1)
        WHERE foo_id IS NULL;
```

UPDATE: this is the new situation after the modification of the data-model.
The point is: legal_entity and client seem to share a key domain (which doe not seen right)  Giving legal_entity its own key-domain seems more appropiate.

```
DROP SCHEMA tmp CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA tmp ;
SET search_path=tmp;

-- user is a special word, then renamed to users
CREATE TABLE users
        ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
        -- name is a special word
        , zname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
        );

CREATE TABLE client
        (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
        );

CREATE TABLE legal_entity
        ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
        , client_id INTEGER REFERENCES client(id)
        , federal_id VARCHAR(14) NOT NULL
        );

CREATE TABLE user_client
        ( client_id INTEGER REFERENCES client (id)
        , user_id INTEGER REFERENCES users (id)
        , legal_id INTEGER REFERENCES legal_entity(id)
        , CONSTRAINT user_client_pkey PRIMARY KEY (client_id, user_id) 
        );

CREATE INDEX tres_stupide ON user_client (client_id) WHERE legal_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: foo_id can not be null fk_1 and fk_2 PKs are the tbl_relation

Comment: Foo_id is a foreign key and can be null. fk_1 is conditional on (foo_id not being NULL).  And I don't understand the rest of your sentence. Maybe the confusion about the OP calling a columns fk_1, which is a very bad name for a column.

Comment: I edited the question, I believe that now is best to understand.

Comment: client_id in legal entity is PK, no sense insert duplicate values in user_client.

Comment: Your data model just does not seem right. the user_client table allows an N::M relationship between user and client. In the text you explain that a client is either a "natural" person or a legal entity. The N::M relation will allow a client to be a collection of persons, and a s to belong to multiple of these collections. The occurrence of client_id as a PK in more than one table is also suspect, IMO.

Comment: Suspect? This is called specialization. The problem is that a client can have multiple users, however if an ordinary person should only have one.