# Custom validation in Rails on different model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I use custom validation between two different models in Ruby on Rails?

I have two models how can I validate columns between these two models.

Comment: could you please describe your models?

Comment: @leafeve https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61594998/condition-between-columns-of-different-models

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way is to create separate validator class instead of just a custom validation method. A validator is really just a subclass of `ActiveModel::Validator` or `ActiveModel::EachValidator` that implements `#validate` or `#validate_each`:

```
class TitleCaseValidator < ActiveModel::Validator
  def validate(record)
    unless record.name[0] == record.name[0].upcase
      record.errors[:title] << 'must be title cased'
    end
  end
end
```

```
class Album
  validates_with TitleCaseValidator 
end

class Book
  validates_with TitleCaseValidator 
end
```

```
class TitleCaseValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate(record, attribute, value)
    unless value[0] == value[0].upcase
      record.errors[attribute] << 'must be title cased'
    end
  end
end
```

```
class Album
  validates :title, title_case: true
end

class Artist
  validates :name, title_case: true
end
```

See [Performing Custom Validations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#performing-custom-validations).

Comment: How can I use this for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61594998/condition-between-columns-of-different-models

Comment: @sbak thats a completely different question.